# Cannot connect to Compute Engine instance via SSH

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud

I've just created an instance using Google Cloud Platform's Compute Engine and tried to connect to it via SSH connection but it failed.

I'm following the quick start [here](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/quickstart).

I have generated the SSH key on my PC and have entered the pass-phrase when asked. Though I fail to succeed a log in :-(

I got the PuTTY SSH's error as below snapshots.

[image]

Then I get the PuTTY window inactive.

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have the same problem but found a workaround to connect via PuTTY manually.

### In brief

1. Generate SSH key for the machine instance
2. Add SSH public key to the instance
3. Prepare to log in - acquiring information for IP, login name, pass phrase, private SSH key
4. Connect to the instance via SSH client, e.g. PuTTY in Windows

### Detail steps

For me the gcloud [quick start](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/quickstart) had already:

- launched my instance
- created my public and private RSA keys (in `C:\Users\USER_NAME\.ssh\`)

Public Key - C:\Users\USER_NAME\.ssh\google_compute_engine.pub

Private Key - C:\Users\USER_NAME\.ssh\google_compute_engine.ppk

[image]

1. Go to the Google Developers Console in your browser
2. Select your project and in the left hand nav bar click: Compute -> Compute Engine -> VM instances
3. Your running instance(s) will be linked below the CPU usage chart
4. Click the one you want and find the `Add SSH key` link and click it
5. Paste the entire contents of `google_compute_engine.pub` into the field that appears
6. Click Save and after a few seconds the key details will appear on the page (if you get an error you pasted from the wrong key file or didn't copy all the text)
7. The first word in those details is your (case sensitive) `username`

[image]

8. Find the `External IP` above on the page
9. Open PuTTY and paste the external IP into Host Name (port is the default of 22)
10. In the left hand nav expand: Connection -> SSH and then click Auth
11. Next to "Private key file for authentication" click "Browse"
12. Select "C:\Users\USER_NAME\.ssh\google_compute_engine.ppk" and click Open
13. Scroll the left hand nav back up and click the top item "Session"
14. Under "Saved Sessions" enter a name and click "Save"
15. Accept the warning message and you should be prompted to login with the `username` from above step
16. Input your passphrase
17. Done

Hope this helps.  If someone has a solution for the gcloud issue I'd love to hear it too.

Comment: This post is long time ago when I still use Windows to develop my apps. Not stop doing that stup*d things ^^ Everything on Ubuntu is very much straight forward.

Answer (score 5):

A non-discussed answer is that you should have at least the standard memory on your VM instance (3.75GB) - do NOT use Micro VM instances.

I could only log in with SSH via browser console or gcloud command line, but not with Putty or Mac terminal SSH. 
I spent an hour on the phone with support and we found this to be the problem.

Comment: Nice sharing @Nth.gol. Thank you! Google Cloud team should give more helpful warning/error messages.

Answer (score 3):

To get identified by ssh you need to run this command, which add *gcloud ssh key* in the list of ssh keys

```
ssh-add google_compute_engine C:\Users\USER_NAME\.ssh\
```

Comment: I had a problem in which using "gcloud compute ssh <instance-name>" I was able to connect, but when using just "ssh" I had to put the <location> and <project> is as well, so "ssh <instance-name>" would give me permission denied, but "ssh <instance-name>.<location>.<project-name>" would connect just fine. Nothing fixed it for me, except for this response, which was simply go to the ".ssh" folder, and run "ssh-add google_compute_engine" and now "ssh <instance-name>" works! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can also connect to your VM instance using embedded in-browser SSH client, see [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser) for how to do that.  That's pretty much a couple of mouse click to do.

Comment: Though working on a web console is quite different, lagging and less-feature compared to local console

Comment: Agree using the in-browser console for emergency situation only.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why, if the user already existed (eg: already SSH logged in google web console), it doesn't work when I manually added SSH keys into metadata on google web console. I have tried hundred of times from the steps below.

I found out you have to manually add your ssh key through web SSH CONSOLE -> ssh in on google web console and copy ssh pub key on your local machine (usually is in ~/.ssh/) and append (edit and paste to the end) it to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys.

Comment: why would you say that? I have micro instances and to some of them I can connect ssh and to the others I am not after some time. did you figure it out why its happening?

Comment: it seems to happen in the older versions of the instance couldn't automatically add the ssh key, just a guess, it's been a while, I kind of not remember

Answer (score 1):

1) SSh into the vm by cloud console.

2) Change the root password `sudo passwd`

3) set below parameters to yes by `nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

PasswordAuthentication
   PermitRootLogin
   PasswordAuthentication

4) restart sshd `service sshd restart`

Comment: This will switch to user+password log-in mode. I prefer using ssh key. Thanks any way!